# can not install react native web-view

Tags: react-native, networking, webview, installation, connectivity

I try installing "react native web view" but when I run "npm install --save react-native-webview" it takes a lot of time and nothing will happen. And when I try using yarn to install the library I get the following error:

```
There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

I do not have any problem with internet connectivity or proxy! I can run npm install well but I cannot install the library at all. 
I have tried to increase npm timeout but the related command does not work too. Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with using these two commands.

npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy